# Full Text Search SQL can't find digital value in nvarchar field

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, fulltext-index

I have a Stored Procedure, which uses full-text search for my nvarchar fields. And I'm stuck when I realized, that Full-Text Search can't find field if I type only numeric values of this field.

For example, I have field Name in my table with value 'Request_121'

If I type `Запрос_120` or `Request` - it's okay

If I type `120` - nothing is found

What is going on?

Screenshots:

1. No results found: https://gyazo.com/9e9e061ce68432c368db7e9162909771
2. Results found: https://gyazo.com/e4cb9a06da5bf8b9f4d702c55e7f181e

Comment: I suppose you mean a numeric value, or a sequence of digits.

Comment: you mean if you type 121 then no result is showing ?

Comment: @YogeshSharma yeah, right

Comment: @Sevastsyan Oseev & your expected o/p would like that 121 or whole string ??

Comment: @SevastsyanOseev Please show us your query.

Comment: @YogeshSharma I expected, that I found value from table which contains '121' in my nvarchar field

Comment: k. then show your like or contain query from which u are fetching data.

Comment: @SevastsyanOseev see my updated answer below which explains the `LANGUAGE` term used for FTS creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot find `121` word part in your full-indexed column because SQL Server treats `Request_121` as a single term. You can verify this by running the fts parser manually:

```
select * from sys.dm_fts_parser('"Request_121"', 1033, 0, 0)
```

Returns:

[image]

while running:

```
select * from sys.dm_fts_parser('"Request 121"', 1033, 0, 0)
```

Returns:

[image]

Note, in the second example `121` was picked as separate search term.

What you could do is to try using wildcards in your FTS query like:

```
FROM dbo.CardSearchIndexes idx WHERE CONTAINS(idx.Name, '"121*"');
```

However, again I doubt it will pick `121` being inside a non-breakable word part, only if you have `121` as standalone word. Play with `sys.dm_fts_parser` to see how SQL FTS engine breaks up your input and adjust your query accordingly.

**UPDATE:** I've noticed that you use Cyrillic search terms together with English. Notice, when running FTS queries it's also important to know what Language was specified when FTS index was created for `Name` column. If the FTS language locale is Cyrillic then it will not find English term `Request` in the `Name` column.

Note, in my `dm_fts_parser` examples above I have used 1033 (English) language id. Examine the `LANGUAGE language_term` operator in your [CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-fulltext-index-transact-sql) statement to check what language was used for FTS index.

Answer (score 0):

> I have field Name in my table with value 'Request_121'

Your query is wrong, you have a typo, write `121` instead of `120`

```
FROM dbo.CardSearchIndexes idx WHERE CONTAINS(idx.Name, '121');
```